# pgfplots: Points with no marks but errorbars?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

How can I plot data points with pgfplots that have no marks, but error bars? If I try `marks=none` and enable errobars, I get big filled circles with errobars. If I change my mark to `mark=+`, for example, I have to adjust the mark size by hand, so that the errorbars are bigger than the mark.

The reason is, if I have error bars, I automatically have the actual data point: the point where the error bars cross. So I don't need an explicit mark , but as described, just setting `mark=none` doesn't seem to be enough to achieve this.

This plots filled circles with error bars as marks even `mark=none` is set:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[ only marks, mark=none,
              error bars/.cd, y dir=both, x dir=both, x explicit, y explicit]
       table [x index=0, y index=2, x error index=1, y error index=3]
       {mydata.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Part of the content of `mydata.txt` to work with:

```
3.414   8E-3    3.62    5E-2
1.570   2E-2    1.65    1E-1
3.809   9E-3    3.96    3E-2
4.340   2E-2    4.34    3E-2
```

**How do I get error bars without an actual mark symbol, so that the point is "auto-marked" by the crossing of the error bars?**

Comment: Could you include an MWE?

Comment: Done. Hope this is enough.

Comment: Sorry for replying late - internet is a little shoddy - but what exactly is in `mydata.txt`?  (`filecontents` is a great environment if you're unaware ;))

Comment: I added a part of the data to work with.

Comment: And I'm assuming that the optimum result would be something of a scatter plot, but with error bars? (Just to be perfectly clear, my apologies)

Comment: Yes, scatter plot seems to be the right term (English is not my native language). I want these (x+-dx, y+-dy) value pairs plotted (with errobars, but with marks and without "connecting lines").

Comment: I would never have noticed, Foo :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `no markers` option to the axis, and then supply `scatter, only marks` to the plot.  Seems paradoxical, but it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.txt}
3.414   8E-3    3.62    5E-2
1.570   2E-2    1.65    1E-1
3.809   9E-3    3.96    3E-2
4.340   2E-2    4.34    3E-2
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[no markers]
    \addplot[scatter, only marks,
              error bars/.cd, 
              y dir=both, x dir=both,
              x explicit, y explicit]
       table [x index=0, y index=2, x error index=1, y error index=3]
       {mydata.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. It should have worked to write `only marks,mark=none`. I will note this on the bug list for pgfplots to fix it eventually.

Comment: Thanks, Christian!  Yeah, it's weird that it doesn't work like that, but it may have something to do with `mark=none` resetting all other options (it said something about this in the documentation).

Comment: This works fine for the plot, but how to create a legend for this plot. Using `\addlegendentry{data1}` will not produce any legend marker as no markers or lines are plotted for this data.

Comment: @Janek well, what would you expect? I've personally no idea what a legend would look like for a plot such as this.

Comment: In principle, I would expect some sort of + with T ends. I want to plot several datasets in one plot using different colors to distinguish them from each other. The legend would then have the same markers but different colors for each entry.